# Building a flow chart in beamer using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to build the following flow chart in beamer and was hoping I might get some answers on how to do it.  What I want looks like this:

[image]

I started doing this with the tikz package but ran into 2 main areas of trouble.

Problem 1) How to get that arrow that correspond to No

Problem 2) How to actually get that figure to fit into a beamer slide.

I will attach the code I have so far.  I have tried using the `\resizebox` command to no avail as well.

```
\documentclass[t,compress,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} %Beamer theme v 2.2
%\usepackage{kerkis}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usetheme{Ilmenau} % Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
%\usefonttheme[mathonly]{serif}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,syntonly,lastpage,hyperref,graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{animate}

\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
\resizebox{2in}{2in}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {User Input};
\node (in1) [decision, below of=start] {Is the input valid?};
\node (out1) [process, below of=in1] {Make of Vehicle};
\node (out2) [process, below of=out1] {Model of Vehicle};
\node (out3) [process, below of=out2] {Body Type};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
%\draw [arrow] (in1)-| ([xshift=-0.25cm]pro1.south west) |- (start);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Feel free to use any commands you want that i don't use or to redfine colors and shapes. I'd also just be happy getting code to do it without actually having to use mine.

Comment: @PierPaolo thanks that should solve my first question, but what about resizing it to fit specifically in a beamer slide?

Comment: Please make your code compilable!

Comment: @cfr code is now compilable.

Comment: Why is there a close vote after 24 minutes? That is too fast!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility using chains:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,chains}

\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=red!30
    },
  process/.style={
    rectangle, 
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=blue!30
    },
  decision/.style={
    rectangle, 
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm, align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30
    },
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
  dec/.style={
    ellipse, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
\centering

%\resizebox{!}{.8\textheight}{% if required
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain=going below,
  every join/.style={arrow},
  node distance=0.6cm
  ]
\node (start) [startstop,on chain,join] {User Input};
\node (in1) [dec,on chain] {Is the input valid?};
\node (out1) [process,on chain,join] {Make of Vehicle};
\node (out2) [process,on chain,join] {Model of Vehicle};
\node (out3) [process,on chain,join] {Body Type};
\draw[arrow] (in1.east) -- node[auto] {No} ++(20pt,0pt) |- (start.east);
\draw[arrow] (start) -- node[left] {Yes} (in1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And now using the `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=red!30
    },
  process/.style={
    rectangle, 
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=blue!30
    },
  decision/.style={
    rectangle, 
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm, align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30
    },
  arrow/.style={draw,thick,->,>=stealth},
  dec/.style={
    ellipse, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
\centering

%\resizebox{!}{.8\textheight}{% if required
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0.6cm,
  every edge/.style={arrow}
  ]
\node (start) [startstop] {User Input};
\node (in1) [dec,below=of start] {Is the input valid?};
\node (out1) [process,below=of in1] {Make of Vehicle};
\node (out2) [process,below=of out1] {Model of Vehicle};
\node (out3) [process,below=of out2] {Body Type};
\draw[arrow] (in1.east) -- node[auto] {No} ++(20pt,0pt) |- (start.east);
\draw[arrow] (start) -- node[left] {Yes} (in1);
\path
  (in1) edge (out1)
  (out1) edge (out2)
  (out2) edge (out3);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Some remarks

- I change from the old `\tikzstyle` to the `\tikzset` syntax.
- If you decide to not use chains, use the `=of` syntax from the positioning library instead of `of=`.
- The `\resizebox` can be used to control the height if required (see the code for the commented out lines).
- I defined a `dec` style using the `ellipse` shape from the  `shapes.geometric` library.
- You can control the distance between the nodes using `node distance`.

Comment: @ZERO You're welcome. Glad I could help. I just updated my answer providing another approach through the `positioning` library.

Comment: how would I add the word No to the side like the answer below does?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out

Comment: Actually, one question I do have, how do you make a single arrow between nodes longer?

Answer (score 3):

This starts from your code, although I am also fond of `chains`. If you make things a little smaller, you don't need to resize the figure. I've also converted your `\tikzstyle`s to `\tikzset` since the former syntax is deprecated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\tikzset{
  basics/.style={minimum width=30mm, minimum height=7.5mm, text centered, draw=black},
  startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, basics, fill=red!30},
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, basics, fill=blue!30},
  process/.style={rectangle, basics, fill=blue!30},
  decision/.style={ellipse,basics, fill=green!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=17.5mm]
    \node (start) [startstop] {User Input};
    \node (in1) [decision, below of=start] {Is the input valid?};
    \node (out1) [process, below of=in1] {Make of Vehicle};
    \node (out2) [process, below of=out1] {Model of Vehicle};
    \node (out3) [process, below of=out2] {Body Type};
    \foreach \i/\j/\k in {start/in1/,in1/out1/yes,out1/out2/,out2/out3/}
    \draw [arrow] (\i) -- node[anchor=east] {\k} (\j);
    \draw [arrow] (in1.east) -- +(20pt,0) |- (start.east) node [pos=.25, right] {No};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: adjusted chart]

## EDIT

If you want to adjust the length of the arrows, here's a version which lets you specify the node distance in mm for each node:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{
  basics/.style={minimum width=30mm, minimum height=7.5mm, text centered, draw=black},
  startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, basics, fill=red!30},
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, basics, fill=blue!30},
  process/.style={rectangle, basics, fill=blue!30},
  decision/.style={ellipse,basics, fill=green!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hierarchy of decisions}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (start) [startstop] {User Input};
    \node (in1) [decision, below=10mm of start] {Is the input valid?};
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\m/\n in
      {%
        in1/out1/yes/15/Make of Vehicle,
        out1/out2//7.5/Model of Vehicle,
        out2/out3//9/Body Type
      }
      {
        \node (\j) [process, below=\m mm of \i] {\n};
        \draw [arrow] (\i) -- node[anchor=east] {\k} (\j);

      }
    \draw [arrow] (in1.east) -- +(20pt,0) |- (start.east) node [pos=.25, right] {No};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, you probably don't want different values for every single one - this is just for illustration:

[image: varying node separations]

But the `chains` library really would be a lot easier ;).

Comment: how do you make a single arrow between nodes longer?

Comment: If you move the lower node down, the arrow will be longer. Is that what you mean? Load the `positioning` library and say `below=10mm of in1` or whatever.

Comment: @ZERO Please see edit.